# A die is thrown 1000 times. Find the limits within which the number of eyes coming up will lie with probability greater than 0.99.

Tags: probability

Friends, I found trouble understanding this sentence. This is an exercise from a homework on The Central Limit Theorem. Can someone explain what this question is trying to ask? Much thanks.

Comment: The minimum number of eyes for $1000$ die rolls is $1000$. The maximum is $6000$. The average is $\dfrac{1000+6000}{2} = 3500$. Find the smallest range that has probability greater than $0.99$.

Comment: *I found trouble understanding this sentence* Me too.

Comment: So what's the meaning of "eyes"?

Comment: The dots on a die are also called "eyes". The term "snake eyes" refers to two dice each rolling one dot.

Comment: I suppose an alternate definition for "eye" of a die might be rolling a 1. So, then you have a binomial distribution, but since the problem related to Central Limit Theorem, I assumed it was looking for the sum of the dice.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_i$ be the number of eyes showing on the $i$-th roll. Then:

$$X = \sum_{i=1}^{1000}X_i$$

$$E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{1000}E[X_i] = 1000E[X_i] = 3500$$

$$V[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{1000}V[X_i] = 1000\left(\dfrac{35}{12}\right) = \dfrac{35000}{12}$$

Therefore, the standard deviation is $\sqrt{\dfrac{35000}{12}}$.

So, you want $P(3500-k\sigma \le X \le 3500+k\sigma) \ge 0.99$. Find $k$.

For $0.99$, you need $k \approx 2.58$. So, this gives the range $$3360 \le X \le 3640$$

Comment: Note: You may be able to use $3360 \le X < 3640$ or $3360<X \le 3640$. I did not calculate those probabilities, but they are right on the cusp.